# AttributeError - module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django

I got this error, but I've done exactly the same:

> AttributeError at /courses/
>      module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'META'

The error is occuring in :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Course

# Create your views here.
def course_list(response):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'courses/course_list.html',{'courses':courses})

#    output=', '.join([str(course) for course in courses])
#    return HttpResponse(output)
```

But the server shows no issues at all.

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 13, 2016 - 13:51:18
Django version 1.10.1, using settings 'learning_site.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function parameter is called `response` but then you use `request` which is a module you import, change the field param to be called `request` or change its usage inside the function to be `response`

```
def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'courses/course_list.html',{'courses':courses})

def course_list(response):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(response, 'courses/course_list.html',{'courses':courses})
```

Comment: (Also, its entirely possible that you may not need to import `request` at all)

Comment: Yeah I realised that. I wasn't done on the course.But I did with impulse. Works fine no! Thanks again!

Comment: @DevBingo - No worries, enjoy!