# How to fix this error module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'META'?

Tags: python, django, django-views, geoip

I'm trying to get the visitor's IP address in my django project, here's the code I followed.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2


def add(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

g = GeoIP2()
ip = add (request)
location = g.city(ip)
longitude = location["longitude"]
latitude = location["latitude"]
user_location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)
```

When I run the server I get the following error and I don't know why

```
 module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'META'
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465214/attributeerror-module-django-http-request-has-no-attribute-meta)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably imported the module `django.http.request` at the top of your file  and so the name `request` clashes with the variable of the same name.
Have a look at  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465214/attributeerror-module-django-http-request-has-no-attribute-meta). `request` in your function should be an `HttpRequest` object, and not a module.